# Where can I get an English Thesaurus file for SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, freetext

SQL Server can use a thesaurus file to do substitutions in free text queries, so that a search for 'IE' might return results with 'Internet Explorer' or 'Quirky Browser' in the text.

Unfortunately the thesaurus file with SQL Server 2008 is empty! Are there any predefined  English SQL Server thesaurus files available out there? I can't find any obvious source from searches.

(Yes, I can build one if needed)

Thanks

Ryan

Comment: liked your example, quirky browser :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can get one from here: 
[SQL Server English Thesaurus for FULLTEXT Search](http://thinknook.com/sql-server-english-thesaurus-for-fulltext-search-2012-02-07/); the site also provides instructions on how to install it.

I haven't used it myself so I can't say if it's good or bad though.

Comment: Wow. I needed that as well. Great!